# Python : Why is single step conversion of a tuple to list and appending to it not working?

Tags: python

```
aTup = (1,2,3)    
print(list(aTup).append(4))
```

Why does it display `None`?

Answer (score 4):

`append` returns `None`, simple as that. It *does* however modify the `list`

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> print(l.append(4))
None
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The reason is that it isn't meant to be called with the return value used mistakenly for an assignment.

```
l = l.append(4) # this is wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the method `append()` does not return any value.

If you want to print the list after the update, you can do the following:

```
aTup = (1,2,3)    
aList = list(aTup)
aList.append(4)
print(aList)
```